# Jquery how to deal with before send

Tags: jquery

I am very new to jQuery and web development. I would rather not use Javascript and PHP (I don't like languages designed like them), but I need to do something in jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url:some_url,
    dataType:"json",
    data:some_data_in_json,
    success : function(response){
    },
    error : function(xhr){
    } ,
});
```

I wanted to show something before this gets a response, so I added this code before the send (which I found in the documentation):

```
$.ajax({
   url:some_url,
   dataType:"json",
   data:some_data_in_json,
   beforeSend: function() {
      console.log('before executed');
       alert('do sth');
   },
   success : function(response){
   },
   error : function(xhr){
    } ,
});
```

But it doesn't do anything. How in jQuery can I know if I change something, that it was changed? I tried use Firebug. 
EDIT
BTW i have jquery 1.3.2 maybe this will tell you more because my knowledge about web devolpment is 0

EDIT
some_url, some_data_in_json are not variables. I only wrote example.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript lib, FYI :)

Comment: Watch out for those extraneous commas after your `error()` functions in both AJAX calls.

Comment: This is example. I knew that jQuery is JS lib. Thats why i have problem because i am forced to use technology that i dont like at all.
I dont understand why people use JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your variables defined? I suspect that the line `dataType:json,` should read `dataType:'json',` -- a string instead of a variable name.

---

`beforeSend` is ["A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent."](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) While it should work with the above fix, it's not really intended to do what you're trying to do.

Since `alert` is a synchronous event, you can just put it before the AJAX call, and the AJAX won't take place until the alert is dismissed:

```
console.log('before executed');
alert('do sth');
$.ajax({
   url:some_url,
   dataType:json,
   data:some_data_in_json,
   success : function(response){
   },
   error : function(xhr){
    } ,
});
```

Comment: I tried do this before but i dont see alert and nothing in console. When i use firebug.
BTW I have jquery 1.3.2

Comment: `$.ajax` has changed a LOT since version 1.3. You should try to get a more current version. [The docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) also say that "As of jQuery 1.5, the `beforeSend` option will be called regardless of the type of request", so taking your code out of `beforeSend` entirely is probably the best solution.

Comment: ok thx. I cant use jQuery 1.5 :/
I will try to write simplest code on my own to learn how it works. And this should help me.